# Django channels for real time app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have started working on Django application which should have a WEB UI to run my custom scripts on another server and I need to see the output in the UI in real time. Importent to see step by step script execution. Question is - how to redirect script output (print, logger for python script) to channels and then push it to the client?

Comment: wouldn't you do that by making an ajax request from client side to server side.

Comment: In this case I need to store the output of the somewhere and make the ajax request each second, maybe it's also a silution. How I can redirect the output of the script which will be used by ajax? Maybe you have some example

Answer (score 2):

I haven't work on Django application but as it's an MVC framework, I suppose my answer would be relevant to your question.

You can make ajax call (maybe with jquery) to your controllers, which in turn initiate your scripts. I think there are two ways of doing this.

First, is to make serial ajax requests to different controllers, which calls different server side scripts. Ex:

```
// Javascript
$.ajax({
        url: '/controller1/',
        data: {
            payload: "Anything"
            // some payload that you may want to pass to controller
            // optional
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // assess results of your call
          }
        }
      });


$.ajax({
        url: '/controller2/',
        data: {
            payload: "something"
            // some payload that you may want to pass to controller
            // optional
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // assess results of your call
          }
        }
      });


# ==== Python  =========
from django.http import JsonResponse

def controller1(request):
    # get data passed along with ajax request
    dataFromClient = request.GET.get('payload', None)

    # send that data to your script, for processing, if required
    resultFromScript = Script1(dataFromClient)

    #return processed data back to client
    return JsonResponse(resultFromScript)

def controller2(request):
    # Similar structure
```

In second method, you can transfer all the payload that may be required by external scripts at once, to a single controller and then let that controller call other scripts and store their results in different variables. And finally serialize results from different variables and transfer back to client as JSON.

I hope this has provided you with some insights.

Comment: But in this case ajax will get the oitput of the script once it will be finished. But I need to see the step by step outpuy. For example I need to run python script with few "print" inside and I want to see those prints one by one instead of waiting when the script will be finished.

Comment: True, I thought this is what you wanted. I think your problem statement is more suitable for "websockets". It don't look much feasible for client to ping for new data from server, in your case. Instead, create a websocket and let server side scripts ping client to push new data. Read about them here: https://www.fullstackpython.com/websockets.html

Comment: You might consider something like term.js; it will allow you to display a terminal console to display your output, if that's the sort of use case you're going for.

Comment: And do you have some example how to redirect output of the script (print or logging) in the real time to the client, "subprocess"?